# Fitting an unusual curve to length at age data

Tags: r, regression, model-fitting

I apologize for the overly simplified data, but I always get scolded for including too much. the full data is here... https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgJEX3KZYGJspmBjAKUrup5UU3Gl?e=dKNuYs I'm trying to fit a curve and get an equation I can use for predicting ages from the lengths of fish in other datasets. I've tried linear models, natural splines, von bertalanfy, gompertz, logistic, and more, but not really capture the data very well.

```
structure(list(Age = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 16), 
    FL = c(96.1891891891892, 201.026845637584, 243.981818181818, 
    274.594594594595, 303.291666666667, 337.677419354839, 378.347826086957, 
    410.4, 475, 415, 708, 754)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The full dataset looks like this...

[image]

As you can see the linear model isn't great. The natural splines is the best so far, but i don't know how to get the equation for that to predict ages. I can see the model summary using

```
lm = lm(FL ~ ns(Age, 4), data=wi.age.length) 
res = resid(lm)
summary(lm)
```

but I don't know how to build the equation from this output. Thanks

Comment: Asking for suggestions for statistical models for your data is off topic for Stack Overflow. if you need statistical advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. Splines don't have closed form equations. If that's a requirements, you'll need to choose a different model.

Comment: I understand but I'm using R for all my analysis and need to know how to do this in R. That is why I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want to predict Age bei FL = 200 you can use `predict()`

```
lm = lm(FL ~ ns(Age, 4), data=wi.age.length) 
res = resid(lm)
summary(lm)

# to predict Age 
predict(lm, FL = 200)
```